# mergeDebugResources FAILED in react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I've been trying to run my react native project via "react-native run-android" but each time i got following error
i tried several methods to solve this problem including clearing gradlew but they didn't work and issue is persisting
I've been struggling with this issue for more than 10 days
Does anyone here has any idea how can i solve this?

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\myuser\AndroidStudioProjects\main>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using
 "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 2 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :**app:mergeDebugResources FAILED**
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
**Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.**
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development envi
ronment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.htm
l#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Error: **Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8**
081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2
-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:621:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:639:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\myuser\AndroidStudioProjects\main\node_modules\
@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllD
evices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\myuser\AndroidStudioProjects\main\node_modules\@rea
ct-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:158:
41)
    at C:\Users\myuser\AndroidStudioProjects\main\node_modules\@react-native-com
munity\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:125:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\TORANJ\AndroidStudioProjects\main\no
de_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:
164:9)
```